# How to derive Region from City in sql

Tags: sql, region, city

I am required to create a new column 'Region'.

I have `City` (there are multiple cities in the list), `County` (multiple counties) and `State` columns available in the source table.

Is there a way to do so in SQL?

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Here is a sample select statement:

Proc sql;

```
Create table test_region as 
  select full name, address, city, state, zip from details
...;
quit;
```

Comment: If this column doesn't exist in the table details you should use command ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN. If this column already exists in the table details you should just add it into your query like ....select full name, address, city,Region, state, zip from details...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I am not allowed to alter the table. I just need to make use of what is available.

Comment: Also if this column doesnt exist you can add constant filed in yr SELECT and test what type will be created (type of column) like '1' as Region. Practice, test and you will win this task

Comment: If you can't alter the table, you could create a view